# How to calculate percentage of each group on a select query

Tags: sql, percentage

I have the query below that counts the amount of occurrences for each group

```
SELECT ss.year, COUNT(*) 
FROM stackexchange_question seq
INNER JOIN secondary_study ss ON seq.secondary_study_code = ss.code
WHERE (seq.evaluation LIKE 'PARTIALLY' OR  seq.evaluation LIKE 'TOTALLY')
GROUP BY ss.year
ORDER BY ss.year;
```

The other  query below counts part of each group

```
SELECT ss.year, COUNT(*) FROM stackexchange_question seq
INNER JOIN secondary_study ss ON seq.secondary_study_code = ss.code
WHERE (seq.evaluation LIKE 'PARTIALLY' OR  seq.evaluation LIKE 'TOTALLY') AND (seq.percentile = 90)
GROUP BY ss.year
ORDER BY ss.year;
```

The first query returns:

```
2008|36
2009|21
```

The second returns:

```
2008|17
2009|11
```

How can I divide each count from each group from the second query by the counts returned by the first query in order to obtain the percentage?

Comment: I would like to know if @Gordon Linoff 's solution could also work for you, As I don't have your data, could you test it for me?

Comment: no it doesn't.

ir returned the following error:

ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = boolean
LINE 6: WHERE seq.evaluation IN ('PARTIALLY', seq.evaluation LIKE 'T...
                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: operator does not exist: text = boolean
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `where` clause from both the queries as a `case` expression. Then count the occurrences and divide one by the other.

```
SELECT ss.year, 
1.0 * 
sum(case when (seq.evaluation LIKE 'PARTIALLY' OR  seq.evaluation LIKE 'TOTALLY') 
      AND seq.percentile = 90 then 1 else 0 end)
/ sum(case when seq.evaluation LIKE 'PARTIALLY' OR seq.evaluation LIKE 'TOTALLY' then 1 else 0 end)
as pct
FROM stackexchange_question seq
INNER JOIN secondary_study ss ON seq.secondary_study_code = ss.code
GROUP BY ss.year
ORDER BY ss.year;
```

Comment: pct is returning values above 1, which is strange por percentege values. I change the denominator by the numerator by the problem still persists (now with differente values but still above 1).

Comment: i modified the query to use `sum` instead of `count`. Try this

Answer (score 1):

Ue conditional aggregation.  Here is a simple way:

```
SELECT ss.year, COUNT(*),
       AVG(CASE WHEN (seq.percentile = 90) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) as ProportionAT90
FROM stackexchange_question seq INNER JOIN
     secondary_study ss
     ON seq.secondary_study_code = ss.code
WHERE seq.evaluation IN ('PARTIALLY', seq.evaluation LIKE 'TOTALLY')
GROUP BY ss.year
ORDER BY ss.year
ORDER BY ss.year;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select (countsTab2.cnt/countsTab1.cnt) * 100.00 as percentage,
            year
from
(SELECT ss.year, COUNT(*)  as cnt
FROM stackexchange_question seq
INNER JOIN secondary_study ss ON seq.secondary_study_code = ss.code
WHERE (seq.evaluation LIKE 'PARTIALLY' OR  seq.evaluation LIKE 'TOTALLY')
GROUP BY ss.yearORDER BY ss.year
ORDER BY ss.year) as countsTab1
inner join
(SELECT ss.year, COUNT(*)  as cnt  FROM stackexchange_question seq
INNER JOIN secondary_study ss ON seq.secondary_study_code = ss.code
WHERE (seq.evaluation LIKE 'PARTIALLY' OR  seq.evaluation LIKE 'TOTALLY') AND (seq.percentile = 90)
GROUP BY ss.year
ORDER BY ss.year) as countsTab2
on countsTab1.year = countsTab2.year
```